# Select users who purchased a set of items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a purchase table like this:

```
+--------+--------+     
| UserId | ItemId |     
+--------+--------+     
|      1 |      2 |     
|      4 |      5 |     
|      5 |      3 |    
|      1 |      4 |     
+--------+--------+
```

I want to select all userids who have purchased items (4,5,6). I am trying with this query:

```
select distinct UserId from purchases where ItemId in (4,5,6)
```

This returns users who have purchased any of those 3 items, but I only want users who have purchased all 3 of the items.

Any thoughts on what I can do? I am using PostgreSQL 8.

Comment: Postgres **8**?  Really? You should plan to upgrade to a supported and maintained version **now**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching the `count(*)` in the `having` clause to the number of items in the set will return all `UserId` who have purchased all items in the set.

```
select UserId 
from purchases 
where ItemId in (4,5,6) 
group by UserId
having count(distinct ItemId) = 3 /*  3 is the number of items to match the set */
```

If there can be multiple rows for a given `UserId` and `ItemId`, then you can use `count(distinct ItemId)` instead.

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QXL12068

Comment: This isn't working for me. It only returns users who have purchased any of those items 3 times, not that they purchased all 3 of those items

Comment: @TomerShemesh If there can be multiple rows for a given UserId and ItemId, then you can use count(distinct ItemId) instead.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Yes it will. I updated the rextester demo to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select userId
from purchase
group by userId
having
    bool_or (itemId = 4) and
    bool_or (itemId = 5) and
    bool_or (itemId = 6)
```